# Persistence error when generating RSA key using RSACryptoServiceProvider

Tags: .net, rsa, public-key-encryption

I'm having problem with weird error when calling `RSACryptoServiceProvider` multiple times to create private/public key pair :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            CreateKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First failure:"+ e);
        }

        try
        {
            CreateKey();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Second failure:" + e);
        }
    }

    private static void CreateKey()
    {
        var cp = new CspParameters
        {
            KeyContainerName = "ContainerKey.1"
        };
        using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cp) { PersistKeyInCsp = false })
        {
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(true));
            Console.WriteLine(rsa.ToXmlString(false));
            rsa.Clear();
        }
    }
}
```

Output of executing above code is (omitts mine) :

```
<RSAKeyValue>[Private key content omitted]</RSAKeyValue>
<RSAKeyValue>[Public key content omitted]</RSAKeyValue>
Second failure:System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Keyset as registered is invalid.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.Utils.GetKeyPairHelper(CspAlgorithmType keyType, CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer, Int32 dwKeySize, SafeProvHandle& safeProvHandle, SafeKeyHandle& safeKeyHandle)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.GetKeyPair()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 dwKeySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
   at RsaTest.Program.CreateKey() in C:\Users\RF185104\source\repos\RsaTest\RsaTest\Program.cs:line 39
   at RsaTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\RF185104\source\repos\RsaTest\RsaTest\Program.cs:line 25
```

Running the above code, the first call to `CreateKey` works correctly, but the second call fails. When re-running the code again, now even first fails, meaning there is something persisted somewhere. But that shouldn't be happening, as setting `PersistKeyInCsp` to false should prevent persistence of the keys. Changing the `KeyContainerName` causes the call to work again, but only once. Next call then also fails.

I believe I have some big misunderstanding of how `RSACryptoServiceProvider` works, as I have no idea how could above error come to be.

The main purpose of this code is to create an RSA key pair without persisting it to local storage, so other applications running on same user cannot access it.

Running Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7.2, happens both in debug and release.

Comment: Setting PersistKeyInCsp to false means delete it on Dispose. There may be a lag before the name is available again... if you want it never written down, just don’t use a name.

Comment: @bartonjs The error still persists after few hours. Can you go into more detail what not giving it name accomplish? I've copied this code from one of our projects so I'm not even sure what is the purpose of the name.

Comment: Giving it a name saves it to disk and makes it loadable by name. If you're passing around the key value, you don't need the name/persisted key. The only time you surprisingly need it is when it's paired with a certificate for SslStream.  My best guess for the error not clearing is there's still an open key handle somewhere, so it's held in pending-delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were having the same problem with our product in production. It turns out McAfee AntiVirus was causing the issue. It logged this message to the application event log

> `username` ran `process name`, which tried to access
>   ...\APPDATA\ROAMING\MICROSOFT\CRYPTO\RSA\ `Windows SID` \ `randomish folder name`
>   , violating the rule "Malware Behavior: Windows EFS abuse", and was
>   blocked. For information about how to respond to this event, see
>   KB85494.

Comment: Thanks for figuring it out. We do have McAfee on our workstations. So this might be it.